# How can I get a EmguCV ImageBox image?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to select a pixel color of the frames of my webcam. So I capture the frames an show then in a ImageBox without any problem. But when I try to access the image stored on ImageBox when I double click on the ImageBox I get a CvException. The exception pop when I try to get the pixel of the image.

> OpenCV: unrecognized or unsupported array type

This is how I capture the frames:

```
// On Form Load
Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        if (cap != null)
        {
            using (Image<Bgr, byte> frame = cap.QueryFrame())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    imageFrame = frame;
                    imageBoxFrame.Image = imageFrame;

                    Bgr color = imageFrame[50, 100];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in DoubleClick Event:

```
private void imageBoxFrame_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeViewObjects.SelectedNode is ColorNode && !isTracking)
        {
            if (imageFrame == null)
                return;

            Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox imageBox = (Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox)sender;
            Image<Bgr, byte> image = (Image<Bgr, byte>)imageBox.Image;

            Bgr color = image[e.X, e.Y]; // This line causes the Exception
        }
    }
```

Apparently the image is not null.
What I doing wrong? Maybe something with thread things?

Comment: Been a while, but you should answer your own question so this comes out of the "open question" queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Question answered by the OP and Answer posting requested. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved it.
>
> I just need to Clone the image because the using statement erase image data. So, on ProcessEvent I just need to clone the frame to imageFrame.

```
imageFrame = frame.Clone();
```

> And have another problem. The correct way to access the pixel data is by [Y,X] not [X,Y].

```
Bgr color = image[e.Y, e.X];
```